# .gitignore un-ignore equivalent in .hgignore

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

In the .gitignore syntax there is an option where you can have a `!` at the beginning of the file and it will un-ignore any previously ignored files.

So I can have the following:

```
logs/*
!logs/stuff.txt
```

And `logs/stuff.txt` will still be tracked.

What is the Mercurial .hgignore equivalent for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equivalent is just adding the file.  Once a file has been `hg add`ed the `.hgignore` file has absolutely no effect on how it's treated, so you ignore `logs/*` (be sure you're in glob mode, not regex mode) and then `hg add logs/stuff.txt`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Thought it might be something like that. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using [regexp syntax](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html#syntax) you can write both rules in one:

```
syntax: regexp
logs\/(?!stuff.txt$)
```